# Create land and sky in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Everyone,

Is there a way that anyone knows of that would allow me to make the rviz environment look like the land and the sky (instead of the standard grid and background color)?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12111/create-land-and-sky-in-rviz?/) by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 353 on 2011-11-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Export your environment as a collada file and then write a node which streams it as a marker (see http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker).

The problem is that it will consume ressources to send regularly the position.
If you want to avoid that, you could write a dedicated rviz plugin.

edit:

1. Follow this tutorial to see a simple example:
   http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes
2. then take a look at the Marker message definition:
   http://www.ros.org/doc/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html
   You can see that using the MESH_RESOURCE type, a model can be displayed in rviz.
   See also http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D
3. Change the tutorial code to send a mesh instead by filling the appropriate fields in the message definition. To start you can use whatever model is available on your machine.
4. Once the model is streamed correctly, you can use a 3d modeler of your choice to create the objects you need using a format that rviz understands (i.e. collada for instance).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2011-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2011-11-28**:
I updated my post to explain more.

**Comment by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on 2011-11-28**:
Is there a tutorial that explains that? What you're saying makes sense, I'm just a little stuck on where the environment gets designed (i.e. where do I make it look like the land and sky), and how I integrate the collada file into a node (i.e. which topic does it publish on, etc)... Thanks!